# qt connect cilds pushbutton

Tags: qt, parent-child, connect

I have

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow  { 

    Q_OBJECT

  public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

  private slots:
    void getData();

  private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Dialog  *second;
};
```

and

```
class Dialog: public QDialog  {
   Q_OBJECT

  public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0); QDialog * dialog;

    QPushButton *pushButton;
    QPushButton *pushButton_2;

};
```

and I can connect pushbuttons in class Dialog with function getData() in class MainWindow (Dialog is a child of class Mainwindow)

I tried

```
connect(*second->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,
                             SLOT(getData()));
```

but I got

```
error: no matching function for call to
‘MainWindow::connect(QPushButton&, const char [11], MainWindow* const, const char [11])’
```

How do i connect them?

Comment: Please use code blocks for code, not quotations. There's a help box in the editor to help you out.

Comment: May be this post will be at your help..
[StackOverflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180162/qt-no-matching-function-for-call-to-mainwindowconnect

Answer (score 0):

if the dialog is child of QMainWindow subclass (as it would be) you should have something like:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(...)
{
  ....

  m_dialog = new Dialog(this);// in .h file it is defined as: "Dialog *m_dialog;"
  ....

  connect(m_dialog->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(getData()));
}
```

you don't have to write:

```
  connect(*m_dialog->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this,SLOT(getData()));
```

take a look at [this](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/signalsandslots.html) qt code:

```
Counter a, b;
QObject::connect(&a, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)),
                 &b, SLOT(setValue(int)));

a.setValue(12);     // a.value() == 12, b.value() == 12
b.setValue(48);     // a.value() == 12, b.value() == 48
```

as you can see you must use pointer and not QObject.